# view contents of large array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I have a very large array I need to check for debugging purposes, problem is it crashes firebug and the like if I try to view the data.

Is there a way I can dump the array to a text file or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just dump it on the document itself? If you are using Firefox, try the following:

```
document.write(myBigArray.toSource());
```

Then copy paste like your usually do on normal website.

p/s: `toSource()` requires browser that supports Javascript 1.3 and above

Comment: Would that be as near to `php`'s [`print_r()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) as JavaScript gets?

Comment: .toSource() doesn't work in non-gecko browsers (e.g. chrome, safari...)

Comment: @Yarin, that's precisely why I mentioned "if you are using Firefox" .. plus the OP is doing debugging so he could just run FF. It doesn't matter if the website visitors don't use FF because the final web page should not contain debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

Opera has scrollable alerts, it's very useful for developing.

EDIT: Tested with success for messages with 500000 lines. You can also copy from it.

Answer (score 0):

Post the array to the server (json/hidden field normal form post), and use your server-side language to save that array dump to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [libraries](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_editor.php) [that can help](http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm) in writing to files. You can use [ActiveX](http://www.irt.org/script/1421.htm), but that binds you to internet explorer for your debugging and that's kind of outside the javascript world.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE you could try copying a string representation of the array to the clipboard.